# Lattice with $3$ operations.

Tags: soft-question, ideals, lattice-orders

If $R$ is a commutative ring and $\mathcal I(R)$ denotes its set of ideals then I know that $\mathcal I(R)$ can be looked at as a complete lattice with intersection $I\cap J$ and addition $I+J$ as operators. However, when it concerns ideals then there is also the multiplication $IJ$. So I discern $3$ binary operators here. Is there a general concept that matches this? I admit that my question is vague, but any information is welcome.

Comment: You are looking for residuated lattices. Unfortunately, I do not know too much about them.

Comment: Seconded. The Wikipedia entry contains some information on residuated lattices, if you want to learn more, you can look at the slides by N. Galatos http://www.karlin.mff.cuni.cz/ssaos/index.html .